# Issues with SQL window function- error that column must be aggregated or in group by

Tags: sql, group-by, window-functions

I have a table called "sales" with two columns: transaction_date, and transaction_amount: `VALUES ('2020-01-16 00:05:54.000000', '122.02'), ('2020-01-07 20:53:04.000000', '1240.00')` 
I want to find the 3-day moving average for each day in January 2020. I am returning the error that transaction_amount must be included in either an aggregated function or in the group by. It does not make sense to group by it, as I only want one entry per day in the resulting table. In my code, I already have the amount in the aggregate function `SUM`, so I am not sure what else to try. Here is my query so far:

`SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) AS Jan20_day, SUM(transaction_amount), SUM(transaction_amount) OVER(ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_average FROM sales WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_time)=1 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_time)=2020 GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time)`

Any insight on why I am returning the following error?

`Query Error: error: column "transactions.transaction_amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is a sample dataset that is not online. Here are more values: `VALUES
   ('2020-01-14 22:55:37.000000', '12.18'),
  ('2020-01-22 00:26:12.000000', '12.67'),
  ('2020-01-19 02:33:10.000000', '12.22'),
  ('2020-01-10 10:22:14.000000', '53.60'),
  ('2020-01-04 01:27:34.000000', '29.13')`

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) AS Jan20_day, 
       SUM(transaction_amount),
       SUM(SUM(transaction_amount)) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_average
FROM sales
WHERE transaction_time >= DATE '2020-01-01' AND
      transaction_time < DATE '2020-02-01'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time);
```

But the basic issue with your query is that you need to apply the window function to `SUM()`, so `SUM(SUM(transaction_amount)) . . .` .

Answer (score 0):

There is need to use [GroupBy](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) Before **Where** Clause

- GROUP BY clause is used with the SELECT statement. In the query,
- GROUP BY clause is placed after the WHERE clause. In the query,
- GROUP BY clause is placed before ORDER BY clause if used any.

---

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) AS Jan20_day, SUM(transaction_amount), 
SUM(transaction_amount) 
OVER(ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time) 
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_average 
FROM sales 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_time)=1 
GROUP BY {property}
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_time)=2020 GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_time)
```